# Microsoft Spy++ logging messages

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I'd like to diagnose the messages send by the system to an application. I'm using `Spy++` tool from `Visual Studio 2017`. When i select a program like `Notepad++` - it works - the spy show the messages but when i select just simple `Windows Notepad` app i can't see any messages when i type into the editor. I've tested it on Win7(64-bit) and Win10(64-bit).

Comment: Is Notepad++ the only other app you've tested it on? Are you certain you are supposed to see any communication when using Notepad?

Answer (score 2):

Spy has two versions if installed on 64 bit windows. Both will list all windows processes and threads.
however:
**64 bit version** of Spy will not log messages for **32 bit** windows, processes and threads and vice versa, 
**32 bit version** of Spy will not log messages for **64 bit** windows, processes and threads.

Answer (score 0):

Try the 32 bit and 64 bit versions individually.

In my case 64bit found no messages while 32bit version did

Comment: This question was asked about a year ago.
I am not sure why this answer was flagged down. this is the correct answer, even though without explanation.

Comment: Just thought I'd share real quick since I was stuck on it for a while too in case someone happened to find this question by mistake like i did. /shrug